# wolfssl 'ecc_mul2add()' cannot be used

Tags: encryption, wolfssl

I checked the source code and found that FP_ECC needs to be compiled.I have added --enable-ecclshamir and --enable-fpecc when compiling, but it still prompts undefined reference to 'ecc_mul2add()' when compiling.And I did not find an example of 'ecc_mul2add()' in the test file.I'm so sorry to bother you with this stupid question.Here is my compile command：‘./configure --enable-eccshamir --enable-fpecc --enable-opensslextra --enable-ecc --enable-ecccustcurves CFLAGS="-DWOLFSSL_TEST_CERT -DWOLFSSL_DER_TO_PEM -DHAVE_ECC_KOBLITZ -DWOLFSSL_PUBLIC_MP -DUSE_ECC_B_PARAM"&&make&&sudo make install’

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wolfssl/options.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h>
#include <wolfssl/ssl.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/random.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/ecc.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sp_int.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/integer.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/wolfmath.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sha.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/error-crypt.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/hash.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/asn.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/aes.h>
//#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sp.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

ecc_key key;
int ret;
WC_RNG rng;
wc_ecc_init(&key);
wc_InitRng(&rng);
int curveId = ECC_SECP256R1;
int keySize = wc_ecc_get_curve_size_from_id(curveId);
ret = wc_ecc_make_key_ex(&rng, keySize, &key, curveId);
if (ret != MP_OKAY) {
// error handling
}

//ecc_projective_add_point();
ecc_point *point_a = wc_ecc_new_point();
ecc_point *point_b = wc_ecc_new_point();

mp_int num1,num2,num3;
mp_init(&num1);
mp_init(&num2);
mp_init(&num3);
mp_set_int(&num1,23);
mp_set_int(&num2,45);
mp_add(&num1,&num2,&num3);

mp_int a,b,prime,order,num;
mp_init_multi(&a,&b,&prime,&order,&num,NULL);
ret = mp_read_radix(&a,key.dp->Af,16);
cout<<"get mp_int af: "<<ret<<endl;
ret = mp_read_radix(&b,key.dp->Bf,16);
cout<<"get mp_int bf: "<<ret<<endl;
ret = mp_read_radix(&prime,key.dp->prime,16);
cout<<"get mp_int prime: "<<ret<<endl;
ret = mp_read_radix(&order,key.dp->order,16);
cout<<"get mp_int order: "<<ret<<endl;
ret = wc_ecc_gen_k(&rng,32,&num,&order);
cout<<"get mp_int num: "<<ret<<endl;

ecc_point* point = wc_ecc_new_point();
//ecc_point* point_res = wc_ecc_new_point();
ret = wc_ecc_get_generator(point,wc_ecc_get_curve_idx(ECC_SECP256R1));
cout<<"get ecc_point point: "<<ret<<endl;

ret = wc_ecc_mulmod(&num1,point,point_a,&a,&prime,1);
cout<<"num1 * point: "<<ret<<endl;
ret = wc_ecc_mulmod(&num2,point,point_b,&a,&prime,1);
cout<<"num2 * point: "<<ret<<endl;

mp_int ka,kb;
mp_init(&ka);
mp_init(&kb);
mp_set_int(&ka,1);
mp_set_int(&kb,1);

ecc_point* point_c = wc_ecc_new_point();

ret = ecc_mul2add(point_a,&ka,point_b,&kb,point_c,&a,&prime,NULL);
cout<<"ecc_mul2add: "<<ret<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `WOLFSSL_PUBLIC_ECC_ADD_DBL` to your CFLAGS. You were on the right trail by adding WOLFSSL_PUBLIC_MP to make some of the low level math calls publicly visible but an extra step is needed for that one.

See: https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/ecc.h#L553-L564

You need the `ECC_API`'s to be non-opaque (IE public API's).

`WOLFSSL_API` == PUBLIC API

`WOLFSSL_LOCAL` == opaque to end user applications.

(Documented at https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/visibility.h#L39-L43)

Defining `WOLFSSL_PUBLIC_ECC_ADD_DBL` will make the `ECC_API`'s be declared as public type `WOLFSSL_API` and you should be all set!

Hope this helps.

- K

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck in your testing and thank you for the great questions!